# re-render content on props change react on new route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

i created this Component on every page - and it is supposed to re-render a new Title based on the props (title) when the route changes

**Summary.jsx**

```
const SummaryBar = (props) => {
 
  return (
    <div className={`w-full p-6 pl-10 pgbackground`}>
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold"> { props.title } </h1>
      <span className='text-[13px]'>HICC Worldwide - Testimonies Administration Portal</span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Dashboard Page -  `/admin/dashboard`

```
const Dashboard = () => {  
    return (
        <ContentArea>
        <SummaryBar title="Welcome To the Dashboard"/> 
        </ContentArea>
    );
}
```

Profile Page - `/user/profile`

```
const Profile = () => {  
    return (
        <ContentArea>
        <SummaryBar title="User Page Content"/> 
        </ContentArea>
    );
}
```

now the problem is that it is not changing, it just remains static.. how can i effect a new title on route change

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Check comments for context.

You are passing a "`getTitle`" prop in Dashboard & Profile components, whereas you use "`props.title`" in your Summary component.
My guess is you meant to use "`props.getTitle`" instead.

Remember that the props your receive have their properties named after whatever your passed when declaring the component. "`getTitle`" stays "`getTitle`", it doesn't magically switch to just "`title`".

Good practice would be to keep "getXXX" names for actual functions & handlers, and use simple names for your values, to avoid confusion.

Comment: ooops its a typo, thanks i just corrected it, it was supposed to be titie not getTitle

Comment: Then it is indeed very weird ! Could you provide your routing too, I will update my answer if I find your problem with that else i'll probably just delete it instead :p

Comment: sincerely, its kept me at a spot for too ong, like what could i possibly be doing wrong...

Comment: Honestly, wild guess: you've put Dashboard or Profile twice in your routing, meaning both route render the same component which in turn sounds like no changes are reflected but there were no changes to begin with.

Comment: let me put up my route also

Comment: i see my mistake in the routing... thanks much... still growing the component and i referenced a wrong value.  i need to boost my debugging skills.

Comment: Don't bug yourself, this is the stuff you check immediately once you've ran into it yourself ;)

Comment: really appreciate, thanks.